# Can't read a const in a class instance?

Tags: c#, constants

I was mildly surprised when the compiler complained about this:

```
public class UsefulClass
{
    public const String RatingName = @"Ratings\rating";
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public void SomeFunc()
    {
        UsefulClass useful = new UsefulClass();
        String rating = useful.RatingName;
    }
}
```

Compiler says, *"Static member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"*

This isn't a problem, `String rating = UsefulClass.RatingName;` works fine.  I'm just curious what the thinking is behind this?  I have an instance of a public class with a public constant on it, why can't I get the data this way?

Comment: It's horrid language design that severely violates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle ... there's no reason for it, and they could fix it, with no impact on existing code, in a moment.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Because constants just aren't instance members; they're statically bound to their respective types. In the same way you can't invoke static methods using instances, you can't access class constants using instances.

If you need to get a constant off an instance without knowing its type first-hand, I suppose you could do it with reflection based on its type.

If you're trying to add a member that can't be modified but pertains to instances, you probably want read-only fields or properties instead.

Comment: You could also wrap the constant in a getter.

Comment: @BoltClock, I tried to test your point with `String something = this.RatingName` inside UsefulClass and got the same error, which is consistent with your answer.  I've always assumed `String something = RatingName` is looking at the instance, but I see now it's uses the Class.Variable description of a static.

Comment: @TomDestry: That's right, just like how you call a class's own static methods using `StaticMethod()` rather than `this.StaticMethod()`.

Comment: @BoltClock, Thanks, glad I asked now.

Answer (score 18):

A "variable" marked `const` is a compile time construct, not an instance member.  You can access it like you would a static variable:

```
public void SomeFunc()
{
    UsefulClass useful = new UsefulClass();
    String rating = UsefulClass.RatingName; // Access as if static
}
```

That being said, I would personally wrap this into a property if it's meant to be used as you described, like so:

```
public class UsefulClass
{
    private const string ratingName = @"Ratings\rating";

    public string RatingName { get { return ratingName; } }
}
```

This would make your syntax work, but also be a better design, IMO, since it doesn't expose your constants publically.

Comment: I disagree with the plan of wrapping it in a getter (that's wrong), but you've provided the right answer initially, at least (so I upvoted you).

Comment: @Noon Silk: I would suggest that this is correct, and not wrong, **if the data should be associated with an instance** (RatingName).  This was how the OP showed it, in which case, it's instance level data, and should be wrapped in a property (even if it's always returning a constant).  That makes the "constant" nature an implementation detail of the type itself.

Comment: Um, if you don't want to expose your constants publicly, declare them private. Not allowing access to public constants via instances is stupid language design that, like all violations of en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle , expose implementation details. There's no semantic difference between const int foo = 3 and readonly int foo = 3, but the language requires that they be qualified differently.

Comment: @JimBalter I do have the constant declared privately here - I'm not sure where your criticism lies, at least with regard to my answer.

Comment: "a better design, IMO, since it doesn't expose your constants publically" -- the best design for not exposing your constants publicly is to declare them `private`. If you *do* want to expose them publicly, the best design is to declare them `public`. Wrapping them in properties is silly busywork forced upon us by bad language design. I thought I made it quite clear that my criticism was of the language design.

Answer (score 1):

Because const in c# are implicitly of static type. And As static members can be accessed only on class member and not on instance, const cannot too.