# accessing variables from another class without instantiating

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm working with a COM library that can throw a lot of error number codes, and to help with that I have a class full of `int` constants that map each error for example: `int ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 1300` means if a function returns 1300 then a file not found error occurred. Either way, I have about 300 variables, and everything was working nicely since I added them in a another partial class of my `MainClass` object. However, I wanted to encapsulate everything correctly and moved all the constants from my `MainClass` into a new class called `ErrorLib` but I got an error saying:

> member cannot be accessed with an instance reference qualify it with a type name instead

I've read up a bit about problems with constants, so I removed the constant keyword but the error still happened. I tried doing a `MainClass : ErrorLib` to inherit from it all the variables but it still won't detect them. I tried instantiating `ErrorLib` as a `err` variable and then using `err.VariableName` to access them but still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Thanks guys. The fix was something so obvious. You answered this SECONDS withing me posting this, to the point StackOverflow won't let me select as correct answer if 11 minutes don't pass. Thanks for the ideas tough.

Comment: You could make the class, containing the 300 variables static. Along with the variables in it.

Comment: This sounds actually like something that you should use an `enum` with explicit values for

Comment: Any advantages on doing this over using constants?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't read a const in a class instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867429/cant-read-a-const-in-a-class-instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> member cannot be accessed with an instance reference qualify it with a type name instead

As the error message suggests, try

```
ErrorLib.ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Oh god...that was so fast it was almost humiliating, and the fact I've been coding in C# for 5 months now is making it a lot worse...Thanks...