# Defining Environmental Variables

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and trying to take what I have learned in PHP / Laravel and transition it over. I am trying to setup a definition list for environmental variables, similar to https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example.

I can't figure out how to get the variables to be in `scope` for me to use other places.

To get started I created a new file URLlist.cs and have this in there:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class URLlist
    {
        public const string getLinks = "https://www.example.com/api/v1/geturls"; 
        public const string postLinks = "https://www.example.com/api/v1/posturls";       
    }
}
```

I was hoping to be able to use something like URLlist.getLinks, URLlist::getLinks, or URLlist=>getLinks. No matter what I have tried, I can't access those variables from within the `Main()` scope.

Do I have to define a class for every URL / variable? Seems really repetitive and like something someone would have solved by now, so I thought I would ask.

Comment: "Do I have to define a class for every URL / variable?" no, but every constant/variable must be within a class, not directly under a namespace, and the class must be either `public` to be used everywhere or `internal` to be used within the same assembly.  I would also say that configuration files and settings are much preferred in .NET to constants in code.

Comment: Sorry, I was moving code around describing the problem at the office and removed the class during the discussion with a PHP developer and didn't realize that until you mentioned it. I put it back in. You mention the configuration files / settings, isn't that what I am putting together? If not can you link me an example?

Comment: no, configuration files are XML files that are read using standard libraries and can be edited by an adminstrator. When you put constants in code you have to rebuild and redeploy to change settings. You can read more at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/) or search this and other sites for examples. For what you've posted, however, `URLlist.getLinks` would be the right syntax - something else is wrong.

Comment: `URLLlist.getLinks` (that should be `UrlList.GetLinks` by the way) should be valid. Are you trying to access the constants from another assembly or namespace? Do you have your references and `using` statements in place?

Comment: Might be helpful to review [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#scopes) and [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/).

Comment: @InBetween To prevent any confusion, you must have meant [using directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) (as in `using WindowsFormsApp1;`) rather than [using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867429/cant-read-a-const-in-a-class-instance

you may refer to this for your concern, to clear things a bit for you.  But the main point here is that, you need to create a read-only property instead of declaring a constant variable

Comment: Without [MCVE] it is unclear why `URLlist.getLinks` did not work in your case. It is also not very clear what exactly you are trying to figure out - it feels like you simply disagree with the fact that [C# does not have global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/c-sharp-global-variables).

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what do you mean here by environment variables, because that may change according to the language.

If you mean to define something generally accessible. Maybe **static properties**?

```
public class GeneralSettings
{
    public static string SettingA { get; set; }
    public static string SettingB { get; set; }
}
```

Or maybe **constants** (which cannot be changed in runtime):

```
public class GeneralConstants
{
    public const string SettingA;
    public const string SettingB;
}
```

---

if you mean something to change the general behavior of the program (while building, debugging, deploying). You can add it to Visual Studio **build settings** like this:

[image]

This approach is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) well documented

Comment: @InBetween, I did not say that consts are variables.

Comment: I never said you did, I was only pointing out that the correct term is *static fields*, not *static variables*. Anyway, the main idea of my comment was that the OP is already using `const` fields which essentially makes your suggestion of using *static* fields moot.

Comment: @InBetween, I made it `properties`, that makes it better. Isn't it correct?

Comment: I was able to do it using `public static string GetLinks = xxx` as you suggested. Then I could call it using `URLlist.GetLinks` Thank you.

Comment: @Alan, you are welcome, just for your information: `public static string GetLinks = xxx` is called a static field. Where `public static string GetLinks { get; set; } = xxx` is called a static property. It is recommended when you expose anything to the public to expose it as a property.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all for a single server but many processes, you can define your environmental variables in Windows so all applications can read them.

You can read them in c# via

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("variable-name")
```